# How can I capture keypresses outside of the terminal on a mac OS with bash/shell scripting? Or is there a better option than bash?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script that will record keypresses outside of the terminal on a mac os and save the results to a text file. I have tried read and script commands, but my understanding is that these are restricted to the terminal.

Comment: Can't really do this with a bash script, this requires reasonably low-level os integration.

Comment: What can I use instead?